# Meaning of "can't tell if he's coming or going"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've heard this phrase in some lyrics and even read it in some online articles.

> don't know if he's coming or going

What's the meaning and correct usage of *coming or going*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one source I can find after a quick search: [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+know+whether+one+is+coming+or+going+and+not+know+if+one+is+...)

#### not know whether one is coming or going

> Fig. **to be very confused**.
>
> - I'm so busy that I don't know if I'm coming or going.
> - You look as if you don't know whether you're coming or going.

That would fit with the songs:

- [**Coming Or Going** (Lyrics) by Jean Shepard](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Coming-Or-Going-lyrics-Jean-Shepard/A01B2953F49B061848256E6E0025CDC6)
- [**I don't know if I'm coming or going** (Lyrics) by Billie Holiday](http://www.sing365.com/music/Lyric.nsf/I-DON%27T-KNOW-IF-I%27M-COMING-OR-GOING-lyrics-Billie-Holiday/447AB0A01CF552F948256A99000A4449)

The last example is telling:

> You've got me on the road
>   Runnin' to and fro
>   Lookin' high and low
>   I don't know if I'm coming or going
>   Since I fell for you
>
> I run up across the town
>   Chasing up and down
>   Having you around
>   I don't know if I'm coming or going
>   Since I fell for you

Comment: It's not any type of confusion. It's specifically confusion caused by stress and overwork (as demonstrated in the *I'm so busy* example).

Answer (score 0):

It's another term for calling someone two faced, or backstaber, or hypocrite

I can't tell if he's coming or going sometime

Comment: Can you identify a reference work that corroborates the meaning that you offer in your answer? The more familiar meaning, I believe, is the one given in the accepted answer to this question.